# How to Track Users

Tags: web-application, defect-tracking, user-acceptance-testing, application-software-testing, user-stories

How do I track the source of each user signup for B2B SaaS product? In other words, how do I check from which source the user landed on my website? I need to track for each individual user.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the source of each user signup for your B2B SaaS product by using a few methods:

1. UTM parameters: Add UTM parameters to the URLs of your marketing campaigns. This allows you to see which campaign a user came from by looking at the URL parameters in your website analytics.
2. Google Analytics: Use Google Analytics to track the source of each user signup. You can set up goals to track signups and see which sources are driving the most conversions.
3. Referral tracking: Use referral tracking software to track the source of each user signup. This can be a simple script that adds a referral code to the URL when a user clicks on a link from a specific source.
4. Landing pages: Create unique landing pages for each marketing campaign and track the number of signups that come from each page.
5. Cookies: Set a cookie on the user's browser when they first land on your site. This allows you to see the source of the user even if they leave and come back later.

By using one or a combination of these methods, you can track the source of each user signup for your B2B SaaS product.